# How to set parameters for search loop?

Tags: wp-query

This is the loop from search.php file:

```
if (have_posts()) {    
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
```

I tried to set parameters like this:

```
$wp_query->set('post_status', 'publish');
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query as needed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify search query and set your parameters with the help of `pre_get_posts`.
Like this.

```
function wpse_custom_get_posts( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
    return;

  if ( $query->is_search() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );
  }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_custom_get_posts', 1 );
```